# Rails How to add Contact form on Page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, contacts

I am using Rails 3, and I'm planning to include a contact form on one of my pages.

Is there a gem or plugin for this? I am looking for the simplest solution possible. I've tried mail_form but it looks so confusing.

Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A contact form is a very simple thing, there is probably a gem for it, but, it would be much easier and less complicated to write one yourself.

Its just a form, with a bunch of fields linked to a controller/model, that can send an email to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice gem named [contact us](https://github.com/jdutil/contact_us). It is really good and under active development, it means it works out of the box with Rails 3.

Comment: I get this error when trying to access localhost/contact_us, undefined method `semantic_form_for' for #<#<Class:0x000001069fa400>:0x000001069f8510>

Comment: I think that you've overlooked the part, where aouthors says about requirements, big bold text: Contact Us requires the Formtastic Gem. Read more about Formtastic @ https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic

Comment: That's exactly why you shouldn't use a gem for something as simple as this. You'll spend more time trying to set it up, than just coding a simple form yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good option for a contact form:

http://www.frick-web.com/en/blog/contact-form-gem-for-rails3

that is a little rails engine, you can customize everything really easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Contact Us gem via this link: https://github.com/JDutil/contact_us The documentation is clear and you can use it simply. I used it without any problem.

Features:

1) Validation
2) Easy/Add remove fields
3) Simple configuration